# Http Post - long delay at state ExecuteRequestHandler

Tags: iis, performance, asp.net, iis-8.5

I have an asp.net mvc website hosted on Windows Server 2012r2 Standard which uses KnockoutJS to display data in a grid. This server is dedicated to the process that I'm having trouble with - it does not server any other requests.

An ajax call is made to a "GetRecords" action of a controller. This returns data for a couple of dozen records very quickly.

The user is able to make amendments to the data and submit for update. The knockout code makes another ajax call, this time posting the records. At this point the site "hangs" for a long time  (over 10 minutes), but it does complete successfully and the updated date is persisted to a database. During the "hang time" the CPU for the IIS Worker Processes hovers around the 50% mark.

I'm trying to figure out what's causing the delay. It seems that the delay happens before the first line of code of the controller action is reached. I've added trace statements to the action and I can see that once the 1st line is executed, then the action completes within a couple of seconds.

From the IIS manager, I've drilled in to "Worker Processes"\"Current Requests" during the time the page is "hung", I can see that the State is listed as "ExecuteRequestHandler" and the Module Name is "ManagedPipelineHandler". There are no other "Current Requests" displayed.

Using the Chrome dev tools, I've captured the json being posted for the update, it is approx 4mb in size.

I've ruled out the problem being caused by bandwidth because I've tested from a browser running locally (on the web server), and I get the same delay.

Any suggestion on config changes I can make in IIS to improve performance of the post?

Comment: It should be a Stack Overflow one, and clearly you did post there, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53961456/http-post-long-delay-at-state-executerequesthandler

Comment: I posted to both because I think it is kind of in both worlds